# How to make arrow in CSS with angle?

Tags: html, css

Now I have the following HTML code that builds arrow left:

```
.item {  right: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(70, 173, 255, 0);
    border-right-color: #AFCDEC;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

I need to make arrow left with angel to up. How I can do it?

Comment: Can I see the HTML - What is the arrow: an icon, symbol or image?

Comment: I dont use symbol, I use `:after`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSS3's [transform](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/).

```
transform: rotate(45deg);
```

http://codepen.io/RobErskine/pen/xZxKjV

Comment: İt rotates but how to do arrow more long?

Comment: just play with the `border-width: 50px 120px 50px 10px;` @Ahmed

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/267/)**

**Preview**
[image]

```
<div class="arrow"> </div>
<div class="arrow left"> </div>
<div class="arrow right"> </div>
<div class="arrow half-left"> </div>
<div class="arrow half-right"> </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.arrow {
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 10px;
  background: black;
  margin: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.arrow:before {
  content: " ";
  width: 10px;
  background: black;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  transform: rotate(50deg);
  left: -10px;
}
.arrow:after {
  content: " ";
  width: 10px;
  background: black;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  transform: rotate(-50deg);
  right: -10px;
}

.left {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.right {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.half-left {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.half-right {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```